# $\lim_{n\to \infty} [n+n^2\log(\frac{n}{n+1})]=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $\lim_{n\to \infty} [n+n^2\log(\frac{n}{n+1})]=\frac{1}{2}$
> How ?

I can see $\lim_{n\to \infty}\log{(\frac{n}{n+1})^n}=-1$ and rest is suggesting that the limit must not be finite.
Any suggestions how to move forward ?

Comment: A Taylor expansion of $\log(1-1/(n+1))$ might help you.

Comment: Also $\log \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)=-\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thanks a lot

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{split}
n+n^2\log(\frac{n}{n+1})&=n-n^2\log\left( 1+\frac 1 n\right)\\
&=n-n^2\left(\frac 1 {n} -\frac 1 {2n^2}+o\left(\frac 1 {n^2}\right)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}+o(1)\\
&\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}\end{split}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$n+n^2\log(\frac{n}{n+1})\\
=n^2\left(\frac 1 n +\log(\frac{n}{n+1})\right)\\=
\frac {\frac 1 n +\log(\frac{n}{n+1})} {\frac 1 {n^2}}$$
Therefore we can use [L'Hospital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) because

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} ( {\frac 1 n +\log(\frac{n}{n+1}))}=0$$
and
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} {\frac 1 {n^2}}=0.$$

From
$$\left( \frac 1 n +\log(\frac{n}{n+1})\right)'=\left( \frac 1 n +\log n -\log (n+1))\right)'=-\frac 1 {n^2}+\frac 1 n -\frac 1 {n+1}$$
and
$$\left(\frac 1 {n^2}\right )'=-\frac 2 {n^3}$$

we get

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (n+n^2\log(\frac{n}{n+1}))\\
=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-\frac 1 {n^2}+\frac 1 n -\frac 1 {n+1}}{-\frac 2 {n^3}}\\
=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^3}{2(n^3+n^2)\\=\frac 1 2}$$